# Vagrant unable to start VM after Windows Update

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, vagrant

All of a sudden, I am no longer able to boot Vagrant VMs.  Here is the error:

```
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.
```

The only change I know of that I have made on my machine is upgrading to the Windows 10 fall update (a.k.a. Threshold 2, a.k.a. update 1511).

What is causing Virtual Machines to not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the Windows 10 update turns on Hyper-V when it runs (I saw a source for this, which I can't find now).  Going into "Programs and Features", choosing "Turn Windows features on or off", unchecking "Hyper-V", and rebooting solves the problem.